# hebrew encoding issue python

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, encode, hebrew

I scraped a website containing hebrew characters and saved the data as a txt file.
When I open it in PyCharm it presents it in Hebrew:

```
   "name":"פראמול אף ושיעול LIFE"}
</script><base href="https://shop.super-pharm.co.il/pharmacy/cold/flu/PARAMOL-AF-AND-SHIUL20%2B30/p/254954"/>
<title>
        ‫LIFE - פראמול אף ושיעול  |  סופר-פארם‬</title>
```

but when I open it in a notepad it presesnts it in chinese:

΀籘̉㰀瑨汭挠慬獳∽樠⁳獣瑳慲獮瑩潩獮•楤㵲爢汴•慬杮∽敨㸢格慥㹤㰠慢敳栠敲㵦栢瑴獰⼺猯潨⹰畳数⵲桰牡⹭潣椮⽬慮畴敲猯数楣污昭牯畭慬⽳楤瑥䰯䙉ⵅ佈䑏䅉匭䥌䵍剅⽓⽰〵〶㘷⼢ਾ琼瑩敬ਾ

When I open it with the open() command it presents the info as gibberish even when I use the encode() command
What's the problem?

```
    file_name = str(x) + '_' + save_file_name + '_superpharm'
    file_out = open(save_file_name + '/' + file_out, 'wb')
    pickle.dump(strsoup, file_out)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Zz9Q.png)

Comment: It should go without saying that you need to show you code. We are on a programming website, why would you ever not show your program?

Comment: added the save command, is that okay?

Comment: Better. The code that creates the file is still missing. But you seem to completely ignore character encodings, that's your mistake. Python does not magically guess them for you, you need to specify the encoding when you save and load files.

Comment: The guides I've read didn't concentrate on this.

Comment: How can I know the encoding and fix the problem?

Comment: The web server tells you the encoding it sends in the `Content-Type` HTTP header. Depends on what you use for scraping, but high-level Python modules like `requests` automatically adapt to that, so typically you don't have to care for that bit. Now, when you write the response text to a file, specify a Unicode encoding (normally you would want to use `UTF-8`). When you `open()` the file again for reading, specify the same encoding. Also, don't use `wb` or `rb` (binary mode) for text files.

Comment: is it in the user header?
profile.set_preference("general.useragent.override",
                           "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36")

Comment: What exactly did you expect to see when you opened a pickle in notepad?

Comment: Moreover: If you're apparently flipping a coin to decide between UTF-8, UTF-16, and Pickle, the right answer is to go read [Pounding A Nail: Old Shoe or Glass Bottle?](https://weblogs.asp.net/alex_papadimoulis/408925)